# RPC response error -32003: error when updating solana nft using metaboss

Tags: solana

metaboss update uri -a 4KmoJffVvFHmNdnHbbjDaWaBTHSfNMqetZVjAVCGyJve-u https://arweave.net/XfP4jW_sF8msGJ5CWQ_ptmjlcYgumlpgKq__QrugU0c -k keypair.json.

keypair address is Em4dctbgQ2nkwRdbj7pdsL5hBVmMe6CoCnCucZvX5J9E

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error and solved with using Solana config command

```
solana config set --url https://api.devnet.solana.com
```

This will work well.